# Unity3D C# - Syntax - GetComponent<Rigidbody>()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax

I've been trying to learn Unity and pretty soon in the tutorials I've found this:

```
private Rigidbody rb;

void Start ()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
```

I'm not knowledgeable with C# syntax so what I really would like to understand is this `function<object>()` syntax.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

This is generics.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx

Essentially you're telling the Unity runtime to give you the RigidBody component. It's similar to doing something like

`rb = GetComponent(typeof(RigidBody));`